# Cannot connect to localhost with React app

Tags: reactjs, networking, connectivity

Ever since I built my new computer I have been having strange connectivity issues with React projects in particular whenever I try to launch them on Localhost. The exact same React app that simply does not connect on my PC works perfectly fine on my Macbook and any other device including my old PC.

This is the error I receive on Chrome (as well as other web browsers I've tried like Edge whenever I launch my React app on localhost:
[image]

I tried turning my firewall completely off and the issue was still not resolved.

Additionally, a few other select programs and websites seem to have connectivity issues occasionally. My PC is plugged in through an ethernet capable and my speeds seem to be solid. However I do notice occasionally my connection even on things like Youtube will just drop and I have to reload the page and it suddenly works again. Any idea as to why I'm experiencing these weird connection issues?

Comment: your react app should run regardless of internet. So i dont think thats the issue. in command prompt (in admin mode) run `sfc /scannow`

Comment: That will check all the system files on the PC and replace damaged ones. Might help, but im not sure